# Local debug Python Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-lambda

I'm developing a lambda function with Python, which will be triggered off a timed event with eventbridge on AWS.
I'm trying to debug it locally, so far I've only managed to make it run, all attempts to run in debug mode following various online guides have failed so far.

**tldr:** **how do I attach a debugger to a locally run Python Lambda function?**

What I've tried so far:

I found mention that when I run sam local invoke with the debug '-d' arg I should be able to attach a debugger:

`sam local invoke -e ./src/event_data.json DataReceiverFunction -d 5757`

So far I have not been able to attach a debugger. Coming from a Visual Studio background where everything is hidden by IDE magic buttons, I've not really done this before.

I've tried starting my function with `sam local invoke...` and immidiately trying to connect a debugger from VS Code, that does not work at all, just get refused connection. I use the following profile for the VS Code debugger:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
              "host": "localhost",
              "port": 5757
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but here is the template for my lambda function:

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template for PythonLambda_DataReceiver

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 300
    MemorySize: 1024
    Environment:
      Variables:
        CONFIG_PATH : config/Develop.ini

Resources:
  DataReceiverFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Layers:
              - !Ref arn:aws:lambda:ap... #AWS Lambda layer
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
```

Comment: So you're following this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html  ? Looks like the issue is the *refused connection*. Can you show us the full error?

Comment: Yes, I followed that document. I get a popup dialog with the error "Connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5757". I get this error even if I did not run the function first

Comment: At this point if you're following the documentation and getting an error, try a video that shows how its done and see what's missing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FINV-VmCXms  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7Ji2UwRCKI this 2nd one looks better

Comment: Actually quite helpful, in that I did not realize I must have a gateway defined for the debugging to work!